# Informatica B2B Data Transformation

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am trying to handle a xsd:choice in the B2B transformation engine.

([xsd examples here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5564971/pubs/thingy.zip))

That is I have a

[image]

And I am only intrested in getting the "one" part

And I only want extract the "one" element not caring from which underlying type it comes from, i.e. I want to put the result into "one" below regardless if it comes from the thingyone, thingytwo or thingythree.

[image]

In XSLT terms I would like to do:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.differentthingies.com/20111119/thingy" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.differentthingies.com/20111119/thingy differentthinggies.xsd">
    <differentthingies>
        <thingythree>
            <one>thisisthingythree1</one>
            <three2>thisisthingythree2</three2>
            <three3>thisisthingythree3</three3>
        </thingythree>
    </differentthingies>
</root>
```

Transformed by

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var1_root" select="ns0:root"/>
        <root xmlns="http://xmlns.differentthingies.com/20111119/anotherthingy">
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">http://xmlns.differentthingies.com/20111119/anotherthingy thingy.xsd</xsl:attribute>
            <thingyone>
                <xsl:for-each select="$var1_root/ns0:differentthingies/ns0:thingyone/ns0:one">
                    <one>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                    </one>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="$var1_root/ns0:differentthingies/ns0:thingythree/ns0:one">
                    <one>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                    </one>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="$var1_root/ns0:differentthingies/ns0:thingytwo/ns0:one">
                    <one>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                    </one>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </thingyone>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
```

Would become

```
<root xmlns="http://xmlns.differentthingies.com/20111119/anotherthingy" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.differentthingies.com/20111119/anotherthingy thingy.xsd">
    <thingyone>
        <one>thisisthingythree1</one>
    </thingyone>
</root>
```

Comment: I got an answer here https://communities.informatica.com/message/25380#25380